# Should the Q-Value of a state-action tuple be updated, if $s_{t} == s_{t+1}$

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Assuming the agent in my environment does an action, however the agent's state does not change. Does that mean the Q-Table gets updated regardless of respective states (current and next) being the same, or do we skip calculating a new Q-Value in this instance?

Answer (score 2):

If the state not changing is a valid transition for the environment (e.g. due to an action result such as running into a wall in a maze, or just random chance), then yes it should be accounted for as normal in updates. After all, time is still ticking, and it will impact mean reward or discounted return calculations.